# Proper usage of React Native's fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am trying to retrieve information from the USDA Database. I am trying to make a JSON request with this URL:

> https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=butter&fg=Dairy%20and%20Egg%20Products&max=25&offset=0&sort=r&api_key=DEMO_KEY

If I just fetch that link, then I receive the JSON response I expected.

```
fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=butter&fg=Dairy%20and%20Egg%20Products&max=25&offset=0&sort=r&api_key=DEMO_KEY')
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : " +error);
    });
```

However, I want it to be broken down into JSON form, so I am attempting to fetch it the following way:

```
fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "format": "json",
          "q": "butter",
          "max": "25",
          "offset": "0",
          "sort": "r",
          "api_key": "MXWwB8DMBxbCIlFHfSevDtp0cIvOofA6Xsn16BYj"  
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : " +error);
    });
```

However, this returns an error that I am missing my API_KEY. Could you please advise what mistake I am making that the API_KEY isn't going through.

Updated attempt (without using POST method):

```
fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/', {
          "format": "json",
          "q": "butter",
          "max": "25",
          "offset": "0",
          "sort": "r",
          "api_key": "DEMO_KEY"
        }
    ).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : " +error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the api accepts post method for `/search` route?

Comment: I'm not sure. I updated my answer to include another attempt without the post method. It still can't find the API_KEY.

Comment: fetch doesn't handle query params for you. You'll need to construct the entire URL + query params string yourself. That's probably why your second attempt is failing.

Comment: pretty sure on your second request you're trying to send the api_key as a body parameter and not as a url variable, probably thats whats wrong.. you should add it to your url instead of to your body

Comment: @MichaelCheng That explains it. Thanks so much